# Which breeds of dogs are easy to train?

Tags: dogs, training

Which breeds of dogs are easy to train? 
I want to own a dog whom I can train on my own very easily

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Collie

Comment: Sorry, but I think this question has a few issues... It's very broad, encourages a subjective list answer model, and it's very opinion oriented. Any dog is trainable, the success of any training is dependent on the owner and it's your skill here that we cannot judge.

Answer (score 7):

There really isn't an easy answer to this, as really all dogs are receptive to training, that's why they're so popular as pets.

In my opinion, working dogs are the most receptive to training. Whether it's a breed that's normally used for hunting (i.e. Labradors, retrievers, pointers, hounds), or if it's a breed that's normally used for herding (i.e. shepherds, heelers).

I say they're most receptive because they've been bred to learn new commands quickly. But it's important to note, what they're also bred for is their energy and stamina. Let a working dog get bored, and they'll find their own entertainment.

Unless you're prepared for the commitment of a high energy dog, then I would say that whether or not the dog is considered easy to train is the last thing you should be worried about. (It's also important to note, that people will base whether or not a dog is difficult to train based on their experiences, which might not even be the fault of the dog).

I would suggest that you pick a dog based on how well you think it fits in your home and your lifestyle. Is it the right size, or too big or small? Do you want to take it on walks/runs every day? Is it going to be around children? Is it going to be by itself while you're at work? Once you pick a breed that fits you, it's easy to get help with the specific training methods.

Here are some links to quizzes that can help you narrow down your decision.

- [Quiz from Animal Planet](http://www.animalplanet.com/breed-selector/dog-breeds.html)
- [Quiz from Purina](http://www.purina.com/dogs/dog-breeds/dog-breed-selector)
- [Quiz from Pedigree](http://www.pedigree.com/All-Things-Dog/Select-A-Dog/Default.aspx)
- [Quiz from Iams](http://www.iams.com/dog-breed-selector)
- [Quiz from SelectSmart](http://www.selectsmart.com/DOG/)

Comment: This is a good answer and deserves more upvotes, even though the question has been closed.